# How to append an integer to an existing binary

Tags: binary, erlang, elixir

Suppose I have a binary like this `<<1,2,3,4>>` and I want to modify it to `<<1,2,3,4,5>>`. How can I do it?

Also, I am trying to convert a list into a binary `[1,2,3,4,5] => <<1,2,3,4,5>>` but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

In Elixir, you can use the `<>` operator:

```
iex(1)> <<1, 2, 3, 4>> <> <<5>>
<<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>>
```

or the binary syntax:

```
iex(1)> a = <<1, 2, 3, 4>>
<<1, 2, 3, 4>>
iex(2)> <<a::binary, 5>>
<<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>>
```

In Erlang, use the binary syntax with `/binary`:

```
1> A = <<1, 2, 3, 4>>.
<<1,2,3,4>>
2> <<A/binary, 5>>.
<<1,2,3,4,5>>
```

Edit: to convert a list of bytes to a binary, use `:erlang.list_to_binary/1`:

```
iex(1)> :erlang.list_to_binary [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
<<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>>
```

Comment: Can you also answer the second part . I tried this inspired by your answer :
        T1 = Enum.reduce(data,fn(x,acc) -> <<acc::binary,x>> end)
But this isn't working where data is a list .

Comment: Added. To do this with reduce, you need to specify the initial accumulator value: `Enum.reduce([1, 2, 3], <<>>, fn x, acc -> <<acc::binary, x>> end) #=> <<1, 2, 3>>`.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking of posting one more question about how to call erlang's BIFs from elixir (I knew how to call modular functions). This saved the trouble.

Comment: I was noticing that if the list contains values greater than 255 I am getting an argument error(if erlang function) or changed values cause default size of the binary elements is 1 byte I guess. How can I overcome this ? Is this even possible ?

Comment: Enum.reduce(an, <<>>, fn x, acc -> <<acc::binary, x::size(16)>> end)
Not working

Answer (score 1):

1. It heavily depends on what you want to append.

The most generic (although probably the most verbose) solution would be to go through the charlist:

```rb
<<1, 2, 3, 4>>
|> to_charlist()
|> Kernel.++([5])
|> to_string
#⇒ <<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>>
```

2. One might use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension:

```rb
for i <- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], do: <<i>>, into: <<>>
#⇒ <<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>>
```

Also since it’s a charlist, one might use [`Kernel.to_string/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#to_string/1):

```rb
to_string [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
#⇒ <<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found:

```
1> list_to_binary([<<"existing binary - ">>, integer_to_binary(1234, 10)]).
<<"existing binary - 1234">>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was noticing that if the list contains values greater than 255 I am
>   getting an argument error(if erlang function) or changed values cause
>   default size of the binary elements is 1 byte I guess. How can I
>   overcome this ? Is this even possible ?

You can't represent the integer `257` in one byte, and its representation in two bytes is `<<1, 1>>`. Do you know why that is?

The string `"257"` and the integer `257` are two very different things. You aren't ever going to see: `<<1, 2, 3, 257>>` in elixir(or erlang) because each number between the commas is an integer that can fit in one byte. In addition, although an elixir string is a binary, a binary isn't necessarily an elixir string. Do you know how that is possible?

You seem to think that the binary `<<1, 2, 3>>` represents the characters `"1"`, `"2"`, and `"3"`.  That is incorrect.  The binary `<<1, 2, 3>>` actually represents the characters named, `Start of Heading`, `Start of Text`, and `End of Text`.  The character `"1"` is actually represented by the binary `<<49>>`:

```
iex(20)> <<49>>
"1"
```

Similarly, the character `"2"` is represented by the binary `<<50>>`, and the character `"3"` is represented by the binary `<<51>>`.  There is no such thing as the character `"257"`--that is three characters `"2"`, and `"5"`, and `"7"`.